# How to get numbered IDs from API when fetching?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to get data, which IDs are numbers and I don't know how to display them, because when I am trying to use for loop or only writing a number (example below) I get an error:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.count; i++){
        console.log(data.countires.i.name);
    }
```

Error:

[image: first error]

or when I write this:

```
console.log(data.countires."1");
```

This error occurs:

[image: error two]

This is how the data looks like:

[image: data]

So how could I write to get data that I need from fetching API so I could display it? Also, I have to do this task without any libraries, with pure JavaScript.

Comment: console.log(data.countires[i]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.countires` is actually an array.  It will have numeric indicies of `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.  In your `for` loop, you can use a dynamic array index (`i`) using the bracket notation, like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.count; i++) {
  console.log(data.countires[i]);
}
```

Comment: It's countires, not countries.

Comment: also, you wouldn't want to use quotes around the console.log statement like `console.log(data.countires."1");` but rather do `console.log(data.countries[1]);`

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for catching that.

Comment: That's a really dumb mistake I made here :D Thank you!

Comment: @EglėGed Also, consider some of the new syntax for iterating, like `for...of`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of  Your loop here works just fine, but as you start to use some of the new iterables, you might consider using the new syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.count; i++){
    console.log(data.countires[i].name);
}
```

It's just a small mistake or you may called this a *typo*.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
for(var i=0; i<data.count; i++){
        console.log(data.countires[i].id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta write data.countries[i] to get the data....and in second case data.countries[1]

And if you want only ids....u can do data.countries[i].id